# SVN: and bash: How to tell if there are uncommitted changes

Tags: svn, bash

I'm trying to wrap a standard sequence of steps in a shell script (linux/bash) and can't seem to figure out how to tell if the execution of `svn status` returned anything. For example

```
~/sandbox/$svn status
?       pat/foo
~/sandbox/$echo $?
0
```

If I delete the foo file, then the

```
svn status
```

return nothing, but the `echo $?` is still 0

I want to not do some steps if there are uncommitted changes.

Pointers greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

Why not test the result from `svn status -q`? Something like:

```
result=`svn status -q`
[ -z "$result" ] && echo "No changes" && exit 1

echo "Changes found"
exit 0
```

If you are using `svn:externals` in your repo please see the comments and the answers below for additional methods.

Comment: Yes, I took this idea and ended up with something very similar:
[code]
if [ -z "$(svn st)" ]; then
    echo "working copy is pristine"
else
    echo "working copy has changes"
    exit;
fi
[/code]

Comment: @fishtoprecords, please submit it as an answer. It's OK to submit an answer to your own question.

Comment: Keep in mind - I don't think this will work if you have externals. You can add `--ignore-externals` to make it work, but then of course it won't check those externals (if you care about that).

Comment: Also this won't work with every svn version. It works for me with svn 1.8.x but it's not working for my colleagues who use svn 1.7.x.

Comment: @AlG haven't found a great one. I just do a normal `svn status` and check if any lines match `^[AMCDG]`. Of course one could also match `?` for new files but I guess this depends on the application.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer won't work if your project contains `svn:externals` references. In that case, `svn status -q` will still produce output even if the working copy has no local modifications. For example, my project depends on several libraries that are each maintained in a separate part of the repository:

```
$ svn status -q
X       Externals/ETCKit
X       Externals/RulesParser
X       Externals/XMLRPC

Performing status on external item at 'Externals/ETCKit':

Performing status on external item at 'Externals/XMLRPC':

Performing status on external item at 'Externals/RulesParser':
```

To account for this additional output, I ended up using `awk`:

```
if [[ -n $(svn status -q . | awk '$1 ~ /[!?ABCDGKLMORST]/') ]]; then
    echo "The working copy at $(pwd) appears to have local modifications"
fi
```

This script takes the output of `svn status -q` and filters out any lines that don't begin with a status code indicating a local change. If the end result is the empty string, then the working copy is clean.

Comment: With svn 1.9.3 - the `-q` flag suppresses output from `svn status` and the above aporach won't work. I had to remove `-q`.

Answer (score 3):

Or you could try

```
svn status | grep [AMCDG]
echo $?
```

should return 0 if there are changes and 1 if there are none

Answer (score 2):

I have implemented something similar a while back. You should not rely on the return value of `svn status`, but parse its output instead. For example you should look for lines starting with "M", "A", "D", etc. You can use **perl** to help you with this. Based on the result of that parsing you'll certainly know if there are changes or not.

Btw it's not normal for `svn status` to return 0 if there are no changes - after all this return code simply signifies that no errors occurred.

Answer (score 1):

You can test the revision number with svnversions from kde.org
http://websvn.kde.org/trunk/KDE/kdesdk/scripts/svnversions?view=log

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution I've used.  Works with svn externals and avoids explicitly listing svn statuses in your scripts (which may or may not be a good thing depending on your point of view).

```
# tested with svn 1.6.11/bash 4.1.2
if [ "$(svn st -q | cut -c -8 | sed '/^[^ ]*$/d' | grep -m 1 '[^ ]')" ]; then
    echo "changes detected"
fi
```

`svn st -q` - lists the statuses without the X for external directories.
`cut -c -8` - drops all but the first 8 columns.
`sed '/^[^ ]*$/d'` - drops the 'Performing...' lines seen when working with externals.
`grep -m 1 '[^ ]'` - the first non-space implies a modification.